# Reporting tool for C++ that shows number of times executed given a line

Tags: c#, java, c++, code-coverage

I would to know if there is a tool in C++ that gives you a report where it displays the following:

1. The source code of the whole project.  Usually one HTML page per source file.
2. Beside the source code, there are line numbers, for readability purposes of course.
3. And for each line, at the left of the line number, there is a value displayed for how many times that line is executed.

Of course, you need to execute a script that runs say unit tests and from there generate a report.

If you are familiar with code coverage tool Cobertura for Java and NCover for C# that's one of its important features.

Comment: How would you know how many times a line is run?  Wouldn't that vary depending on the usage of the app?

Comment: A predefined set of unit tests have to be made.  Of course you don't use code coverage reporting when the app is in production.

Comment: valid question, but I am not sure that this warrants the java / c# tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at that [list of Code Coverage Tools for C and C++](http://www.codecoveragetools.com/index.php/coverage-process/code-coverage-tools-c.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you use gcc as you compiler you can generate gcov output. Use [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) to create an executable that generates profiling output and then use [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) to generate nice HTML output for your code.

Answer (score 0):

See [SD Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CppProfiler.html).   It produces an output just as you like, but as a GUI rather than HTML.